# Defining ng-view="NAME" from RouteProvider

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm really new to Angular and I have a little question about sending a template or URL into a ng-view. But the way I intend to do I may have to ng-view in my base template.

When my template base is like this:

```
<body>
   <div ng-view></div>
</body>
```

And my JS looks like:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[])
.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', '$httpProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/home', {
        templateUrl: '/contato'
    })
(...)
```

Works fine loading URL inside ng-view when I have only ONE ng-view case, HOW ABOUT IF I need to have more then one ng-view to load ? (like: ng-view="area1" and ng-view="area2")

I've tried in each $routeProvider, but won't work:

```
    $routeProvider
    .when('/home', {
        area1: {templateUrl: '/path1'},
        area2: {templateUrl: '/path2'}
})
```

How would be the right way to set each ng-view separately?

Appreciate any help! Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, as you know now, you cannot have more than one ng-view on your page. You should have a look at UI-Router from AngularUI which does exactly what you are looking for (https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router).

An example from their doc (https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router#multiple--named-views):

**setup**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router']);
```

**html**

```
<body>
    <div ui-view="viewA"></div>
    <div ui-view="viewB"></div>
    <!-- Also a way to navigate -->
    <a ui-sref="route1">Route 1</a>
    <a ui-sref="route2">Route 2</a>
</body>
```

**template 1**

```
<h1>State 1</h1>
```

**template 2**

```
<h1>State 2</h1>
```

**js**

```
myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $routeProvider) {

  $stateProvider
    .state('index', {
      url: "",
      views: {
        "viewA": { template: "index.viewA" },
        "viewB": { template: "index.viewB" }
      }
    })
    .state('route1', {
      url: "/route1",
      views: {
        "viewA": { templateUrl: "route1.viewA.html" },
        "viewB": { templateUrl: "route1.viewB.html" }
      }
    })
    .state('route2', {
      url: "/route2",
      views: {
        "viewA": { templateUrl: "route2.viewA.html" },
        "viewB": { templateUrl: "route2.viewB.html" }
      }
    });
});
```

Here you could specify a controller at the state level, that would be effective for both views, or at the view level, in order to set two different controllers.

**Edit:** Live demo from ui-router docs (http://plnkr.co/edit/SDOcGS?p=preview)

Comment: I've been seeing a lot of UI-Router in SO lately. I think I might give it a try on a project I'm working on which could use some extra views for a single page.

Comment: I added the plunker demo for the example, have a look and see if it fits your needs!

Answer (score 3):

Basically you can't have two ng-view. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17544558/multiple-ng-view-in-single-template-angular-js) SO question:

> You can have just one ng-view.
>
> You can change its content in several ways: ng-include, ng-switch or mapping different controllers and templates through the routeProvider.

Comment: To have 2 ng-views based on routes though, they will need two app modules configured, for the same route but different templates.

Comment: You are write.  I was under the impression you could have more than one ng-app on the page.  Now that I have tested it and looked at the documentation, I stand corrected.