# How can I render two angular.js views on the same page?

Tags: angularjs

If I have two `<div ng-view></div>` elements on the same page, angular.js only uses the first one. I am looking to have two templates (with two controllers and two partials) rendered on the same page, how do I do that? The code below does not work but I'd like to have something along these lines.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-6 small-12 columns">
    <div ng-controller="SitesHomeCtrl" >
      <div ng-view>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="large-6 small-12 columns">
    <div ng-controller="UsersMeetCtrl" >
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks like it was asked before with the answer given as ui-router http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17544558/multiple-ng-view-in-single-template-angular-js

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ui-router is the best option but if you are going with `$routeProvider`, you could use `ng-include` (with `ng-show/ng-hide`) or `ng-switch` to achieve the same.

Comment: Thanks, ng-include looks good for what I would like to achieve at this time. `ui-router` looks like a good solution for some later tasks, however  ;)

Answer (score 4):

I imagine you're probably going to want to look at [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) in place of angular's router at this point, as angular's router does not support multiple ng-view elements.