# AngularJS Having multiple views alternative

Tags: angularjs

I am currently having one

```
<div ng-view></div>
```

inside my AngularJS application index.html, where I load different templates based on different routes and I was wondering if it is possible to have something like components/ mutltiple views or whatever in index.html so that I can load more than one templates in the same page. For example (Login, newsletter...etc). Thanks

I already know that you can only have one ng-view so I am looking for alternative solutions

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17544558/multiple-ng-view-in-single-template-angular-js

Comment: @PascalLeMerrer No I've seen this question already and understand that there can be only one ng-view but was wondering what are the alternative approaches?

Comment: Create more than one angular app, or use ng-include to place more html templates in one view.